# Apply limitTo only to certain group of items

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.items = [
    {"name":"laptop","color":"green"},
    {"name":"shoe","color":"blue"},
    {"name":"Car","color":"gold"},
    {"name":"Car","color":"gold"},
    {"name":"Car","color":"gold"}
];
```

How can I limit the items that contain name = 'car' to 2 yet keep other items unaffected in `ng-repeat`? If I do `<li ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {name: 'car'} | limitTo: 2">`, it will return 2 car results, but then the other items are gone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your scenario sounds more like something related more to a "business logic" than a feature a framework should incorporate. Try implementing your own custom filter.

Something close to:

**custom filter**:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).filter('myFilter', function() {
  return function(items, param1, param2) {
    return items.reduce(function(a,c){  var count = a.filter(function(item){ return item.name ===param1; }).length; if(count<param2 || c.name !== param1 ) a.push(c); return a;},[]);
  };
});
```

and in your **html**

```
 <li ng-repeat="item in items | myFilter:'car': 2">
```

Of course you could extend and perform the actions that are more suited to your app needs.

Here is [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/qUa9QSLRM0IFV7oW6ztU?p=preview)

Comment: what is function(cell) cell here?

Comment: filter function will return items in an array every time the function is true. Cell is the item in the array actually

Comment: I see. what is function(a,c), where does a and c come from?

Comment: It is the reduce function, where a is the last returned value and c is the current value. This function will add into 'a' the items from the original array if they are not found more than 'param2' times. a is initialize as [] empty array. Reduce will iterate through each of the items, the "iterated" item is represented by c